# Image not show asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, image

If I run my webapplication the application work right. When I try to publish with the file system the images doesn't show. The images are included in project and in the publish folder I do find the images in the image folder. 
but is does not show. There is no error, so I do not know where I had to look. Does somebody can help me with this? The image is a simple html tag.

```
<img src="~/Images/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not mix `~` with non runat="server" control :

But you can do this :

```
<img  src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo.png") %>'/>
```

MVC  :

```
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png" )"
```

Comment: It doesnt fix the problem. When I use <img src="~/Images/logo.png"> and  run in visual studio I can see the images, only when i'm publishing the webapp it does not show the images. That is strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an ASP.NET webform project? If so, update it as follows:

```
<img src="~/Images/logo.png" runat="server" />
```

Comment: No i do not use webform. I use MVC Razor

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to set up your image. Either one should work for you.

`<img src="/Images/logo.png" />`

`<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.png" runat="server" />`